# Google sheet limit, number of sheets per workbook

Tags: google-sheets

I know that Google sheets has a 2 million cell limit.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en

but was wondering is there a limit to the number of sheets? the old google sheet has this limit. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-limits-of-Google-Sheets

I can't seem to find any references on the limits for the new google sheet except that 2 million cell limit.

Comment: How many sheets do you need? What's is the real-life case that requires so many and how do you handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reported limit outside the number of cells.  There is a limit of 50000 characters in a cell, easily tested by trying to add more, so other limits may be found which are not listed.

There are also limits inferred by taking the cell limit into account.  Meaning 2 million 1 cell sheets, or 2 sheets at 1 million cells.

Answer (score 2):

Today, i have a SpreadSheet with 1200 Sheets. Each Sheet have one cell (1 row and 1 column).
Therefore, if the limit of cell is 5 millions ... maybe it can give an idea, or not.